# Strategy.close not referencing correct value

Tags: pine-script

Here is the link to the strategy in question:

[MACD Strategy](https://www.tradingview.com/script/BZpiYB82-TR-MACD-Strategy/)

When I plot Long_SL, Long_TP, Short_SL and Short_TP they all appear with the intended values. But when I use them as a strategy.close condition, they don't work as intended.

An example of this can be found in lines 72 and 73 of the script.

I am very new at this, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Long_SL >= low` condition is never true, and this `strategy.close()` is never executes:

```
if strategy.position_size > 0 and strategy.position_entry_name == "B" and Long_SL >= low
    strategy.close (id="B")
```

To check it comment all plots and add

```
plot(low, color = color.red)
plot(Long_SL, color = color.orange)
```

Checking for conditions is always easy with `bgcolor()`:

```
bgcolor(strategy.position_size > 0 and strategy.position_entry_name == "B" and Long_SL >= low ? color.red:na)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out and sharing that handy method of verification. Any help on getting it to trigger a strategy.close when Long_Sl or Long_TP value is met?

Comment: Well, if `Long_SL` is meant to be stop loss, you should be using `strategy.exit("Exit", "B", stop = Long_SL)`

Comment: Understood the issue and fixed it, thank you!